# Why do breakpoints sometimes not work in visual c++ 2008 express?

Tags: visual-c++, ide

What's the root cause?

I can't reproduce it,but sometimes the breakpoint can't let the programme pause.

Has anyone else ever step into this case?

Comment: Really belongs on StackOverflow, does it not?

Comment: You'll need to add more details about your specific situation if you want useful answers. Code samples, etc.

Comment: please don't crosspost; this will be migrated to Stack Overflow automatically.  if you associate your accounts you'll be able to regain ownership of the question after it's been migrated. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the Visual Studio debugger that would cause this. A description of the problem and link to a hotfix is on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026510/).