# When debugging unittest in visual studio the debugsession just quits

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I've had this occur to me daily now. I am debugging my libraries using unittests. My libraries are all code projects inside a single solution.

So I'm stepping through the code and all of a sudden it just continues as if I would've pressed F5, which I didn't.

**Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing here? Anyone else experiencing this problem?**

I'm using the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010. My libraries are all written in .Net 3.5.

Comment: Does it happen when using keyboard shortcuts?  There was a bug where hitting a key would cause a toolbar button to be "clicked".  WAG, and it only ever happened to me when typing in the WF designer...

Comment: Yes, it happens when I press F10 to go to the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was present in VS2008 SP1.  There was a [post-SP hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026510/visual-studio-debugger-skips-over-breakpoints/2157691#2157691) that solved it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they checked the fixed back into the trunk, the bugs came back in VS2010.  This is not uncommon for hotfixes.

Well, no quick fix or well documented workaround I'm afraid.  You could post to connect.microsoft.com to remind them about it.  Hopefully it will be covered by SP1, you might want to consider moving back to VS2008 while you wait for that.