# Surprising CLR / JIT? behaviour - deferred initialization of a local variable

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-3.5, clr, jit

I have just encountered something quite bizarre running an app in `Debug` mode (`VS 2008 Express`, `Any Cpu`). I would appreciate if someone enlightened me as to what is happening here?

```
// PredefinedSizeGroupMappings is null here
Dictionary<string, int> groupIDs = PredefinedSizeGroupMappings ?? new Dictionary<string, int>();

// so groupIDs is now initialized as an empty Dictionary<string, int>, as expected

// now: PredefinedSizesMappings is null here - therefore I expect sizeIds
// to be initialized as an empty dictionary:
Dictionary<string, string> sizeIds = PredefinedSizesMappings ?? new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

// but at this point sizeIds is still null! :O That's what debugger shows.
var groupsReport = new AutomappingReportArgs();

// only once we get here - it's suddenly not... The debugger shows: "Count = 0"
var sizesReport = new AutomappingReportArgs();
```

The `AutomappingReportArgs` class has no connection whatsoever to the `sizeIds` variable, although its constructor does alocate a number of dictionaries:

```
public AutomappingReportArgs()
{
    ChangedNames = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    CreatedAfterRename = new Dictionary<string, string>();            
    Existing = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Created = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Failed = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

I guess it must be some sort of compiler or CLR optimization, but I would like to know the mechanism of it in more detail. What is the reason for this "deferred initialization"?

And why is it inconsistent, why does it work straight away for `Dictionary<string, int>`, but not for `Dictionary<string, string>`? Is it because the compiler can't see any `Dictionary<string, int>` initialization ahead, so it can't put it aside for later?

Comment: Did you clean your build and try again?

Comment: I repeated it several times. Clean it in what sense?

Comment: Clean as in right clicking the Solution then "Clean Solution".

Comment: No such thing in VS 2008 Express

Comment: There should be a Rebuild then.

Comment: This I did, yet it keeps on behaving the same way.

Comment: At a guess it looks like your code and built assemblies are out of sync. Try deleting the `bin` folder.

Comment: @Oded thanks for looking into it anyhow. Baffling

Comment: Put in some line printing the value of `sizeIds`s in there. Don't trust the debugger.

Comment: Well indeed it does print out that the variable is not null. And the debugger "wakes up to that" as well, instantly. The previewed value isn't null anymore.

Comment: so you probably found a VS2008 express debugger issue, not a CLR issue :)

Comment: I did not think of it as an issue at all - since it never fails to initialize the variable before it's actually used in code. Trying to imagine what was going on, I suspected that it can perhaps look ahead and see "ok, there's a bunch of empty `Dictionary<string, string>`s getting allocated on the next stack frame anyway, so let's wait with this one until then and get all of them done in one go", thereby speeding things up somehow. (???)

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard behavior when you debug optimized code.  Unlikely to be the case here.  Likely to be a bug in the debugger instead.  There was an important post SP1 hotfix for VS2008 that fixed a number of debugger problems.

You'll find the link to the hotfix in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157691/17034).  Not so sure how applicable the hotfix is to the Express Edition, you should be okay but I can't guarantee it.