# How does the C# operator `??` works?

Tags: c#, operators

I was working with `??` operator in C# 4 and found a interesting feature.

This line of code **always** assigns null to `existingObject` if it is already `null` regardless of the `searchForObject()` return value *(searchForObject returns a not null object, in fact it is a linq statement not a function and if the following statement will be replaced with simple if construct then existingObject will be assigned a not null object)*:

```
    existingObject = extstingObject ?? searchForObject();
```

Could someone explain why?

Here is [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to MSDN, it says:

> A nullable type can contain a value, or it can be undefined. The ??
>   operator defines the default value to be returned when a nullable type
>   is assigned to a non-nullable type. If you try to assign a nullable
>   value type to a non-nullable value type without using the ?? operator,
>   you will generate a compile-time error. If you use a cast, and the
>   nullable value type is currently undefined, an
>   InvalidOperationException exception will be thrown.

The part about assigning a nullable type to a non-nullable type is not what I expected.

**The problem was deferred initialization of local variables in the debugger of Visual Studio 2010.**

Comment: Apparently `searchForObject` method returns null.

Comment: Perhaps because `searchForObject()` always returns null/

Comment: Have you stepped though it in the debugger? Do you have code for searchForObject() ?

Comment: Sorry was not clear enough, no searchForObject does not return null

Comment: There is also a chance you're not actually looking at the same code that you're executing. It happens sometimes in Visual Studio. Rebuild the project, try clearing the bin folder, put some `Debug.WriteLine`s in to trace what's really going on in your app (instead of relying on the IDE's `Watch`), etc.

Comment: Did you try to debug and step into searchForObject to see if it actually returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what I said in this comment:

> There is also a chance you're not actually looking at the same code
>   that you're executing. It happens sometimes in Visual Studio. Rebuild
>   the project, try clearing the bin folder, put some `Debug.WriteLine`s
>   in to trace what's really going on in your app (instead of relying on
>   the IDE's `Watch`), etc.

another question comes to mind - is `existingObject` really null after the assignment? :) How have you asserted that?

Have a look at my question (and the answers):

[Surprising CLR / JIT? behaviour - deferred initialization of a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615943/surprising-clr-jit-behaviour-deferred-initialization-of-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 3):

The `??`is shorthand for

```
if (somethingisnull)
  somethingisnull = somethingnotnull
```

Therefore `searchForObject()` must be returning null as well

Comment: In fact if I use this construct I get a value.

Comment: What Type is existingObject and what Type is searchForObject returning?

Comment: searchForObject code is irrelevant, it could be anything, try it yourself, I think the catch is assigning the object to itself.

Answer (score 2):

> ??  returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null;
>   otherwise it returns the right operand.

```
   // ?? operator example.
    int? x = null;
    // y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1.
    int y = x ?? -1;
```

Comment: Yes, this is an example from msdn which also say that ?? is used to assign a nullable types to not nullable types

Comment: you can't assign null to not nullable types

Answer (score 2):

Read : [Coalescing operator - ??](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/coalescing-operator.html)  : Coalescing operator is new operator added in C#2.0. Coalescing operator is also known as ??.

*Without ?? operator*

```
 Nullable<int> a = null; 
Nullable<int> b = 10; 
int c = a==null ? b.Value : a;
```

*Can be replace with ?? like as below*

```
Nullable<int> a = null; 
Nullable<int> b = 10; 
int c = a ?? b.Value;
```

`??` is oeprate allows to assign second value if the first one is null

```
existingObject = extstingObject ?? searchForObject();
```

so in your case if `extstingObject`  is null tha its get the value of `searchForObject()` and assign to object , if you are getting null than the second function also return null also.

Answer (score 1):

There is something else going on here, `searchForObject()` must return `null`. Take a look at the following example.

```
object searchForObject()
{
    return new object();
}
```

With this implementation of `searchForObject()` we can do this:

```
object existingObject = null;
existingObject = existingObject ?? searchForObject();
```

Now if we test this out simply like this:

```
Console.Write("existingObject is ");
if (existingObject == null) Console.WriteLine("null");
else Console.WriteLine("not null");
```

It is going to tell us that `existingObject is not null`. However, if we change what `searchForObject()` returns to this:

```
object searchForObject()
{
    return null;
}
```

It is going to tell us that `existingObject is null`. Now, a last test is to change the value of `existingObject` before we do the first check:

```
object existingObject = new object();
existingObject = existingObject ?? searchForObject();
```

This will tell us that `existingObject is not null`.

If `existingObject` is null, this means that whatever is after `??` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is somewhere else is wrong. In this line of code, the return value of *searchForObject()* will be assigned to *existingObject* if *existingObject* is null.