# How to force debugger to skip a piece of code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

There is huge amount of code in my project which already debugged 50% of it.
Every time I try to debug it I have to manually set breakpoints after unwanted piece of code to skip it.
Is there a way to tell debugger not to debug that part of code ?
Any extension for this ?

Let's face debugger is on line 1500.

```
Method1(){
   Line 1500 CODE
   Line 1501 CODE
   ...
   Line 1726 CODE
   Line 1727 CODE
   ...
   Line 2200 CODE
}
```

I won't need to debug lines between 1727 and 2200.

**NOTE : It's not just one piece. Otherwise I would be fine with manual breakpoints**

Comment: If it would really skip those lines and your code is not executed, won't that break the rest of your code?

Comment: @MrFox It must get executed but not debugged.

Comment: @MrFox - OP means he doesn't want to manually debug through these (or set breakpoints after), just have the debugger jump over them automatically.

Comment: I think this would be a great feature.  While I agree with @Oded that in some scenarios (this one) a refactored method would work, there are other scenarios, like ones that involve events that are constantly hit (*cough* OnPaint) that you may want to, on-the-fly, tell the debugger to not run during your debug session (semi-permanent, but not permanent).  Like a breakpoint... or a "skippoint" (tm)... Perhaps a VS extension should come our way ... ;-)

Comment: Another scenario this would be handy: a place where your stupid coworker thought it was a good idea to put a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() that gets hit 100% of the time.  ARGH!

Comment: Related posts - [Visual Studio Debugger skips over breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2026510/465053) & [Skip current line in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31474563/465053)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the code in question is encapsulated in a method, you can skip the method by applying the [`DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) on it.

Other than that, setting breakpoints is how to do it.

So, extract this code into a method and apply the attribute to it ;)

Comment: @Mahdi - What do you mean?

Comment: The CODE you see in my question is inside one method which might call or not call another methods.

Comment: @Mahdi - I still don't follow. If you take the lines between 1727 and 2200 and extract them into a method and then put the attribute on that method, the debugger will not go through that method.

Comment: The ignored code is related to other parts of code so I can't do that

Comment: @Mahdi - You probably could, using the `Extract Method` refactoring.

Comment: @Mahdi: You should be able to extract parts of your method into another method without problems. Actually, it usually is a bad sign to even have a class with over 500 lines. Let alone a single method...

Answer (score 26):

Don't know why it's not in the answer but you can set next statement by **CTRL+SHIFT+F10** or dragging the yellow arrow to wanted line and code before next statement will not be executed.

Found it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/07/30/debugging-101-how-to-skip-over-code-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also click on the line you want to skip to and hit Ctrl+F10 (Run to Cursor). It will jump directly to that line.