# Skip current line in debugger

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way of skipping the current line in the Visual Studio debugger using keyboard shortcuts?

The only way I was able to do it is using the yellow cursor on the left or "set next statement" which does not work at the end of a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Debugger skips over breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026510/visual-studio-debugger-skips-over-breakpoints)

Comment: It's a completely different issue. If I step, it will not skip the End Sub at all.

Comment: Related post - [How to force debugger to skip a piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15023996/465053)

Comment: @RBT the article tells you how to skip the debugger, I wanted to skip the execution

Comment: Is skipping the debugger and skipping the execution not the same thing? The idea is to jump from one line of code to another line of code without executing the lines in between.

Comment: No, skipping the debugger means that Visual Studio/whatever will not stop on that line during debugging, but the runtime will execute it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The "Set Next Statement" (CTRL+SHIFT+F10) shortcut will work at the end of a function... but you need to use the mouse though as well.

Comment: I tried it with VS 2013 and it worked for me. Sorry for that

Comment: On VS 2019 there are those green arrows in front of lines, hold CTRL key and you can set next statement directly there, skipping anything in between.