# Strange behavior: Visual studio 2008 with SP1 step over when debugging will skip lots of statements

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

Windows 8 64 bit, Visual Studio 2008 SP1, the break point can be hit, but step over after several steps from the break point will suddenly "jump" to statements far after the current running statement.

Has any of you experienced this before?

Thank you

Comment: Is your program compiled with optimizations enabled?

Comment: No. It was set as: Disabled /Od

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Debugger skips over breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026510/visual-studio-debugger-skips-over-breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

OMG.
Install hot fix "KB957912" sorted out my problem.

You can download it from [here.](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796)

You can refer to a more detailed discussion about this at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/1e67b428-acff-4649-91c6-127fe3b80626):